# Gradle issuess - Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, gradle

I get this Error massage

> > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> >     Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>
> ```
> google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at
> ```
>
> https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.

my gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
     android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.books.mrwan.qasswanwadar"
                minSdkVersion 17
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.0'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
        }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

what I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the word `compile` to `implementation`

and change all the version of the google library to 15.0.0

**Example:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

Should be working.

Comment: how can i change the version of the googel library

Comment: @MrwanYassinALGANAD just change it inside the build.gradle app

Comment: I did not find googel library into build.gradle app?

Comment: @MrwanYassinALGANAD `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'` . Those are google library.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: @MrwanYassinALGANAD try **Clean** and **Rebuild**.

Comment: same error :   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex